# Unity - How to write a "Behaviour" or script for entire scene (in C#)?

Tags: c#-4.0, unity-game-engine

I am starting to learn Unity.

As I understand, We can write scripts(behaviors) in the form of C# files and apply them to each objects on the scene.

But how to write a script for the entire scene? I know this is a obvious question - there has to be a script for the entire scene so that all my objects "behave" in a synchronized way and it's gotta be pretty basic, but preliminary Google searches has not borne much fruit.

Can someone give me a quick guide?

Comment: can you describe the behavior you're trying to create?

Comment: Say I have 3 boxes in a scene. Now, the possible movements for the first box will depend on the positions of the second and third box, while the position of the second box will depend on the position of the third box.
Basically, I am looking to create a single C# script file which will control the behavior of all the boxes present in a scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your "boxes" example comment I would do the following:

1. Create an empty gameobject, let's call it `BoxesController`...
2. Attach below `BoxesController.cs` script to it
3. In the editor inspector reference all boxes

#### BoxesController.cs

```
public class BoxesController: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform box1, box2, box3;

    void Update() {
        // change boxes position
    }
}
```

Now imagine you will need to have > 30 boxes in current scene... You will have a lot of work to reference each box. So you could change your script if you add a `Tag` to all boxes. Let's say you create a new tag inside Unity Tag Manager called "Box" and give it to all boxes.

You now can change `BoxesController.cs` script to the above and you will not have to reference all boxes in the Editor Inspector because they will be searched and referenced inside `Start` method.

#### BoxesController.cs

```
public class BoxesController: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject[] boxes; 

    void Start()
    {
        boxes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Box");
    }

    void Update() {
        // change boxes position
        foreach (GameObject go in boxes)
        {
             //get box name
             string box_name = go.Name;
             // get box transform property
             Transform t = go.transform;

        }
    }
}
```

Please note that `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` is a heavy operation and that's why I did it in the `Start` method and saved the result to reuse it in `Update` method calls.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is create an empty GameObject and add a script to it and use one of the techniques described in the link to get access to the 3 boxes you want to move.

http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Game_Objects.html

In this case you probably want to use "1. Through inspector assignable references." which just means create a public Transform variable in the script, save, then in the Inspector drag the box in the slot that appeared in the script-component

edit: for further reading i'd suggest googling the term "Game Manager" in combination with "Singelton" and "Unity" :)